# What is the policy for bulk question moving towards newer SE sites if fulfilling certain criteria

Tags: discussion, policy

What is the current policy to move questions on certain event?

For example, site "Software Engineering" has about 45K questions; I think many of them relate rather to the topic "DevOps" - for example the query on Software Engineering SE for

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=continuous

returns about 2K questions!

So, assumed it could make sense to move questions forth to newer, more specific communities, what is the current policy for that?

Comment: That question has already been answered on meta.devops also: [Should we start moving on-topic questions from SO and Serverfault to here?](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/should-we-start-moving-on-topic-questions-from-so-and-serverfault-to-here).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Questions that are on-topic on a site should not be moved to another site where they're also on-topic, even if the latter is somehow "better".  This is the guidance that SE gives for migration of individual questions, and it should apply in bulk too.

People chose to ask those questions on their original site, and members of that community answered.  This activity builds the repository of knowledge on that site, and might also produce reputation for the participants.  Yanking those posts away harms the community that invested that effort.  Further, communities sometimes have different standards (e.g. for what counts as backing up an answer), so even if you weren't worried about damaging the original community, you might end up adding stuff that *doesn't meet the new site's guidelines*.  That, too, causes harm.

A new site should grow organically.  The only time SE bulk-moves questions is if a site is closing, a rare event.

Answer (score 14):

We don't do bulk migrations for a lot of reasons.

Unless those questions are deemed off topic on the original site, we have no cause to remove content from an active site… which would also remove reputation from the original authors who asked those question on the original site.

It can also be harmful to the *new* site.

The wholesale importing of content from elsewhere is not a great way to build a new community. Questions imported from elsewhere would likely be *orphaned* if the author does not have an account there. The tags would not likely match, and the migrated questions would by-pass the automatic dupe-checking to make sure the question hasn't already been asked. Anonymous content also has that odd, back-dated feel, of long-forgotten posts that no one really cares about any longer. And if someone were to post another answer or comment on one of those old threads, no one would likely receive the notification as they do now.

Essentially, we would be loading this site up with a lot of questions asked and answered a long time ago… **without imparting any of the benefits of reputation, ownership, or experience into the *new* community who is supposed to take care of it.**

That is why we don't do it.

Answer (score 6):

> So, assumed it could make sense to move questions forth to newer, more specific communities, what is the current policy for that?

Your assumption is false.  Old questions *aren't* moved to newer sites.

Either the question is appropriate on the old site, in which case there's no reason to move it (and it would cause lots of problems *to* move it) or it *wasn't* an acceptable question on the original site, in which case the question has a lot of baggage (in the form of downvotes, close votes, comments explaining why it's off topic, etc.) that would cause problems on the new site, along with the fact that the question simply wouldn't have been crafted with the new site's audience in mind.